# coldfusion loop is dropping links

Tags: loops, hyperlink, coldfusion

I have a graphic on my page and will be imposing some links over it.

```
  <p><img src = "ind-pict-05.png" alt = "ind-pict-05.png" 
       class = "webresponsive" 
       style = "width:100%; position:relative;
                z-index:0;  "></p>
       <div style = "position:absolute;top:15%;left:59%;width:16%;height:81%;
               z-index:1;border:2px solid blue">
          <div class = 'rainbow'>
          <a style = "cursor:pointer" onclick = "window.open('ind-acct.cfm')"></a></div>
         
          <div class = 'rainbow'
          <a style = "cursor:pointer" onclick = "window.open('ind-donor.cfm')"></a></div>
    </div>
```

And the css:

```
 .rainbow {
  margin-top:1%; 
  height:7.4%;
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

This works.

[image]

In in the image, the blue box shows that everything is properly positioned, and the red boxes, the div's that contain the links, also show correct positioning.  (These debugging tools will be dropped in the final version.)  The links are working correctly.

There will eventually be 12 red boxes, so I thought I would put it in a loop.  Trying with just two boxes the code is:

```
     <cfset linkarr = ListToArray('acct,donor')>  
     <p><img src = "ind-pict-05.png" alt = "ind-pict-05.png" 
       class = "webresponsive" 
       style = "width:100%; position:relative;
                z-index:0;  "></p>
     <div style = "position:absolute;top:15%; left:59%;width:16%;height:81%;
               z-index:1;border:2px solid blue">
     <cfoutput>
         <cfloop array = '#linkarr#' index = 'abc'>               
             <div class = 'rainbow;'>
                <a style = "cursor:pointer" onclick = "window.open('ind-#abc#.cfm')"></a>
             </div>              
         </cfloop>
   </cfoutput>
```

This does not work.  The div class = "rainbow"and associated link do not appear.

[image]

The developer tool is showing the code in place, although it is not showing any formatting except what is inherited from the top div (not shown here):

[image]

Can anyone tell me why writing out each individual link works, but looping through the links is not working?

Comment: `<div class = 'rainbow;'>` is incorrect. There are no semi-colons in class names.

Comment: Also converting a list into an array does not make a lot of sense. You could use `<cfloop list="acct,donor" index="...">` straight-away.

Comment: Tomalak, yes it was the bad class which made the red border disappear  -- I think I automatically type a lot of ; just because of javascript.  However the links are still not there.  Any further thoughts?  Re the list to array, intended to loop over the list, but was getting some strange errors, so I tried an array instead.  Don't know whether any of that is relevant.

Comment: You need the link in the red boxes to be clickable? Are there any styles for the links? Links without any content has a 0 width and height

Comment: @ThumChoonTat -- the links are working just fine when I don't use a loop.  And they work thoughout the div.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the loop that's the problem, it's the html inside it and outside it. If you compare the generated html from both approaches, you'll see what the differences are.

Others have already pointed out the errant semi-colon after the classname in your CF approach:
`<div class = 'rainbow;'>`

Two other issues:

You have missed the closing outer `</div>` on the CF version.

@Thum Choon Tat is right in saying that the links with no content have zero width and height.
In your plain html approach, you have missed a `>` on the second inner div opener:

`<div class = 'rainbow'`

...this is what causes the link to appear to work without the loop, because the browser is trying to fix the invalid html, and in my browser at least this results in the `div` being part of the link instead of its parent.

If you fix all these errors in the html you should see that both approaches result in the same behaviour - links with zero width and height due to having no content inside them - it was never a problem with the loop not working, it was a problem with the non-loop version that made it appear to work by chance.

Comment: Sev, you are no doubt right that I messed up the html.  I'll be checking it out shortly.  It is so hard to see one's own errors. Re the zero width,height:  the link is working throughout the entire <div.  Perhaps specifing the width and height  overrides the default zeros.

Comment: Sev, I've checked this over.  I put back in the missing > in the non-loop section, and the link fails to execute.  I think I went through that experience before.  Following up on Thum Choon's point that there is no size to an empty div, I put some stuff in there.  It didn't help.  Without the > it works fine. I'd really like to fix it however, because while it works in firefox, perhaps it won't work in other browsers.

Comment: Sev The closing </div is in my code, but was farther down and didn't make it into the sample.    Re the loop, I've had to abandon it, because it turns out the tabs in the rainbox are not equally spaced and I had to line up the div's by hand.